# Issue with TreeTableColumn custom setCellFactory not updating UI immediately

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `TreeTableColumn<ProjectView, ComboBox> treeTableColumn`. I set a custom cell factory, where I set the width of the ComboBox to be the same width of the column itself. The UI itself won't update until I start scrolling up and down the TreeTableView.

Hopefully, the code below is all the relevant code.

```
TreeTableColumn<ProjectView, ComboBox> treeTableColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Description");
treeTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("comboBox"));
treeTableColumn.setCellFactory(col -> {
            TreeTableCell<ProjectView, ComboBox> cell = new TreeTableCell<ProjectView, ComboBox>() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(ComboBox item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    ComboBox newItem = new ComboBox();
                    newItem.setMinWidth(this.getWidth());                   
                    this.setGraphic(newItem);                   
                }

            };
            return cell;
        });

treeTableView.getColumns().add(treeTableColumn);
```

Additionally, I have this method that will change the data in the tableview. This method is called when the user changes the selected item in a dropdown menu:

```
...
TreeItem root = new TreeItem();
projectList.stream().filter((p) -> (p != null)).forEachOrdered((ProjectView p) -> {
            TreeItem project = new TreeItem(p);
            root.getChildren().add(project);
        });
treeTableView.setRoot(root);
...
```

As you can see, this is a very dumbed-down implementation of the cell value factory. I've removed as much extra code as possible to try and pinpoint the issue, but even with this implementation the ComboBox's that are initially displayed all have the wrong width. Once you started to scroll up and down through the TreeTableView the ComboBox inside the cells start to display correctly using the correct width.

I've seen several posts that deal with similar issues but none of their fixes seem to work. 
I've tried calling refresh, I've tried toggling the visibility of the col and tableview in question. I've ensured that the super method is called and setGraphics is always set in the update method I'm overriding in the setCellFactory method. I'm sure I'm missing something, but I just don't see it. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

Here is a min example that reproduces this problem. I should note that after posting this, I found if I wrap the update in a Platform.runLater thread, it works, but that dosen't feel like the right way to do it.

```
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javafxapplication;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TreeItemPropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFXApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TreeTableView treeTableView = new TreeTableView();

        treeTableView.getColumns().clear();

        TreeTableColumn<ProjectView, ComboBox> treeTableColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Dependencies");

        treeTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("comboBox"));

        treeTableColumn.setCellFactory(col -> {
            TreeTableCell<ProjectView, ComboBox> cell = new TreeTableCell<ProjectView, ComboBox>() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(ComboBox item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    ComboBox newItem = new ComboBox();
                    newItem.getItems().add("Test");
                    newItem.setMinWidth(this.getWidth());
                    this.setGraphic(newItem);
                }

            };
            return cell;
        });

        List<ProjectView> projectList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            projectList.add(new ProjectView());
        }

        treeTableView.getColumns().add(treeTableColumn);

        TreeItem treeRoot = new TreeItem();
        projectList.stream().filter((p) -> (p != null)).forEachOrdered((ProjectView p) -> {
            TreeItem project = new TreeItem(p);
            treeRoot.getChildren().add(project);
        });
        treeTableView.setShowRoot(false);
        treeTableView.setRoot(treeRoot);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        root.getChildren().add(treeTableView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class ProjectView {

        public ProjectView() {
        }

        public ComboBox getComboBox() {
            ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
            cb.getItems().add("Test");
            return cb;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I would like to run your code on my machine to see if I can reproduce the behavior you are describing. In order to do that, I think you should [edit] your question and post a [mcve].

Comment: Added an example. I also note that I found if I wrap the update in a Platform.runLater thread then it seems to work, but that really doesn't seem like the right way to fix it.

Comment: don't use nodes as data ..